# How can I find substring value and copy in another column in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a SQL statement where table contents consisting of columns like empid,event,date. now event consists of some data which contains a string éntry'in it and the second row will contain éxit'in it. I know how to create a new column by using alter command. but I do not know how to capture the event column data which has éntry'or éxit' in it? can someone guide me on this issue?. my task is to create a new column and add the substring data of event column which has ÉNTRY'or 'EXIT'in it?

```
Empid | Event            | Date
------+------------------+------
  1   | BLOCK-ENTRY      | 01-03-2017
  2   | BLOCK-EXIT-DOOR  | 01-03-2017
  3   | BLOCK-DOOR-ENTRY | 01-03-2017
```

This is the table format and I have created a column as

```
alter table tablename 
    add newevent varchar(10)
```

After this I have to get the ÉNTRY' OR ''EXIT'value from the event column and update into the `newevent` column

Comment: I tried to add table values and alter command in the above question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update yourtablename
set neweventcolumn = case when event like '%ENTRY%' then 'ENTRY' 
when event like '%EXIT%' then 'EXIT' end
```

The like predicate will change depending upon your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SQL query which will give you the 'Entry'or 'Exit' as 4th column and then you can use it in your newevent column.

```
Select 
    empid,
    event,
    date,
    CASE
      When CHARINDEX('ENTRY', dbo.TableABC.event) > 0 Then 'ENTRY' 
      When CHARINDEX('EXIT', dbo.TableABC.event) > 0 Then 'EXIT' 
    ELSE 'No Event'
    END AS 'Event Type'
 From TableABC
```

Hope this helps.